# Error inserting polygon using Python Console in Qgis GIS software

Tags: python, pyqgis

I just started using Python Console in Qgis GIS software. I want to add a polygon using the Python Console that exists in Qgis. I tried to combine the codes I found from a few documents.
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points])
The above line of code says "expression cannot contain assigment, perhaps you meant "=="?" warning is coming. Akcakent table can be edited in Qgis. Where is the error in the code I wrote? Can you help me?

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('akcakent')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(layers[0].dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), '', 'ogr')
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())

    feat.setAttribute(
            [124067558, 637773842, 18, 616, 150216, 'KIRŞEHİR', 'AKÇAKENT', 'YAYLAÖZÜ', 120, 18,
             'CEMALETTİN', 'YILMAZ', 11, 996, '15.10.2019 00:00:00', '15.10.2029 00:00:00', 'CEVİZ',
             'YAYLAÖZÜ 120/18'])
    points = [QgsPointXY(34.053635541202, 39.59019921065601),
              QgsPointXY(34.053837103237, 39.59035923430099),
              QgsPointXY(34.053332895004, 39.591078697114966),
              QgsPointXY(34.052752319765, 39.590607693827991),
              QgsPointXY(34.052868265722, 39.590297176571),
              QgsPointXY(34.052315209862, 39.589806031292),
              QgsPointXY(34.052372452976, 39.589741092592988),
              QgsPointXY(34.053635541202, 39.59019921065601),
              QgsPointXY(34.053635541202, 39.59019921065601)]
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points])
    (res, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing **akcakent** attributes would help.

I add some comments, and use a fictive data to reproduce the error. After checking step by step your code, it misses one close parentheses from the above last line.

```
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]) --> feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]))
```

In addition to that, I set the attributes line by line to make sure the adding new features, for example:

```
feat.setAttribute('attrib1', 'attrib1 value')
feat.setAttribute('attrib2', 'attrib2 value')
```

Finally, you should set the scale in order to display the layer because it seems that the scale is very large (1:1000) , and make sure your project has the same projection/coordinate reference system as your passing coordinate (I mean your layer).